# How to change socks5 if dead cURL

Tags: php, curl

i have script to check something with socks all is ready but when its socks5 dead not change to try other socks from list, look below and please help anyone to fix that :

```
$ch = curl_init();
if($sock!=''){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $sock);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dattt);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
```

Comment: Just to check, you want to attempt to connect via one socks proxy, but if that doesn't work, change to another socks proxy?

Comment: i need to change automaticaly if dead ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php

$hosts = array(
    'xx.com',
    'yy.com'
);

class TimeoutException extends \Exception {

}

class Curl
{

    public function connect($sock, $ch, $dattt, $url)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $sock);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dattt);

        // etc
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // 28 is curl timeout
        if (curl_errno($ch) === 28) {
            throw new TimeoutException;
        }

        // some other error handling...

        return $result;
    }
}

$curl = new Curl;
foreach ($hosts as $socks) {
    try {
        $result = $curl->connect($socks, $curlResouece, $dattt, $url);
        break;
    } catch (TimeoutException $e) {
        continue;
    }
}

if (!isset($result)) {
    die('Failed all socks');
}

echo $result;
```

As for an explanation, you're looping through the socks proxies you've specified. If the CURL error is 28, it'll throw a timeout exception which you catch in the try catch block. You can then continue to the next proxy. If is has a result, it'll break from the foreach and return the result straight away. If all of the socks proxies are unavailable, it'll die an error.